# choosing the number of clips generated arround the selected temporal position?

Tags: neural-networks, references, dataset, pattern-recognition

in the article [Learning Spatio-Temporal Features with 3D Residual Networks
for Action Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07632), it says that for choosing the samples for training from videos:

> We first select temporal positions of each sample by uniform sampling.
> 16 frame clips are generated around the selected temporal positions.

I want to understand if I change the number of frame clips generated, does it affect the training when using fine tuning? In other words, should I train the dataset from scratch with the the different frame number and then use the model for fine-tuning?